# iTunesConnect beta testing

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to use the new iTunesConnect beta testing. I am trying to invite a user to test however he already has an iTunes Developer account and it won't let me invite him because it of this:

> The email address you entered already belongs to an iTunes Connect
>   account. To continue, enter a different email address.

I searched around but found no solution. What are my options in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: i connect testflightapp.com try it but i study how it works with i tunes connect...

Comment: @Bimawa, it is pointless to waste your time on testflightapp.com, the site will be shut down on __26 Feb 2015__, in about 4 weeks' time.

Comment: have you tried to add the tester as an _external_ tester? for me it worked well before Christmas.

Comment: @holex Yea i know it. I moved all tester to iTunse connect. All fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you can only invite internal testers beta testing through Apples beta testing system. The definition of an internal tester is someone who is actually in your iTunes Connect team. An email address can only be associated with one iTunes Connect team and because your tester already belongs to another team they can't be added to yours.

You can always do an AdHoc build for them just the same as you would have done before the Apple beta testing system came online. Provision their device, archive and build an ipa and then upload it to TestFlight.

Comment: but i don't understand how there are users can download a build? Only from testFlight?

Comment: Yes if you use the AdHoc build and upload to test flight. They will receive an email saying a new build is available and they will be able to download the app.

Comment: ok. But it's work fine without adding tester in iTunes connect, i just adding their in testFlight. And iTunes connect can add only 25 users no more. For what we need iTunes connect beta-testers?

Comment: The big difference is there is no need for provisioning of devices.

Comment: This sucks but I guess ill have to live with it. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 0):

You can also send them the build (.ipa file) of your app and they can re-code sign the app with their developer certificate (see image). They can then install it on their devices or put it on the iOS simulator.

Here is the (re)code sign terminal command:

```
#! /bin/bash
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform /Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer" $1.app
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is simple:

- All client Apple Ids as internal testers (if possible).
- All my company Ids assigned as external testers in client's account. It's not so problematic task when you maintain CSV in format `John,Appleseed,appleseed_john@mac.com` that you can import in iTunes Connect:

[image]

It also kind of makes sense, that you need to fill a "what should testers test" form for external users (my company's testers), because client in most cases knows what should be tested - unlike my testers, who needs to be notified somehow what is the status of the build and what should be tested.